# Email a row from grid using email button?

Tags: extjs

I am new to extjs.
I am trying to email a row based on user row selection 
The user first has to  select a checkbox from a row and click on  the email button at the bottom of the toolbar panel.
The grid has only one email button at the bottom.

How can I emaila row when the user selects a checkbox to select a row and click on the email button to send the email and attach the information in the row using extjs?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to send email (except [mailto](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_mailto)) in javascript, you must send the request to your server where  it can be processed and emailed.